# Preventing Facebook Android SDK from displaying password as plain text

Tags: android, facebook, passwords, password-protection, facebook-android-sdk

I have an Android app using the Facebook Android SDK and will be deployed publicly.

My problem is that whenever a user makes a mistake logging in with a wrong password, the Facebook SDK will change the password field to plain text, which is obviously not going to be acceptable in a public environment.

Is there a way to suppress this behavior?

Comment: The dialog login workflow (being a webview) is entirely controlled on the server side, and there's no client-side flag to disable it as far as I know.

Comment: @Ron No such problem for me on Android 3.2. I am using Facebook Android SDK 3.0. I think I had such a problem on iOS but I was not using the latest version of the Facebook iOS SDK.

Comment: If Facebook wants the field to be non-shrouded after an error, that would seem to be Facebook's choice to make, if it is Facebook's field and not yours.

Comment: Extend the offending class and provide your own web view which adds Javascript to change the plain text password fields to a hidden password, and make sure yours is called instead. This might be against the tos though.

Comment: is there way to encrypted password without login button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Facebook SDK login dialog validating flow is managed from the server side of facebook. And as we do not have any control at our side for login validation.

The Facebook SDK provides a LoginButton view that is a custom view implementation of a Button. You can use this button in your app to implement Facebook Login. The LoginButton class maintains the session state, which allows it to display the correct text in the button based on the user's authenticated state. Adding LoginButton to your activity's layout is a quick way to implement Facebook Login.

Along with the login button, you may want to control other user interface (UI) components based on whether the user is authenticated or not. The Facebook SDK includes two classes: `UiLifecycleHelper` and `Session.StatusCallback`, to handle much of the complexity around managing session state changes. The activity or fragment where you show authenticated functionality can create an instance of the `UiLifecycleHelper` class and pass in a `Session.StatusCallback` listener that is notified of any session state changes. Your activity or fragment must call `UiLifecycleHelper` public methods that mirror an activity's or fragment's lifecycle methods. These methods are used in creating, opening, saving, and restoring an active Facebook session. The `Session.StatusCallback` listener implementation can override the `call()` method to respond to session state changes and update the UI accordingly.

So `LoginButton` controls the login button functionality and you can add custom code triggered off the `call()` method to control other UI components.

Comment: I haven't tried your answer, but it does give me an idea on how to go about my problem.

Comment: is there way to encrypted password without login button?

Answer (score 2):

No, the login dialog is rendered from Facebook's side and the mobile login dialog always shows the password in plain text on the second try - there should be a note to that effect visible in the dialog when it reloads